# How to test custom validations in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM and are about to write some test cases. Im new at this and wonder how I can proceed to test the component below?

```
public class CustomValidation : ComponentBase, IDisposable
    {
        private IDisposable? _subscriptions;
        private EditContext? _originalEditContext;

        [CascadingParameter] EditContext? CurrentEditContext { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public bool DoEditValidation { get; set; } = false;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            if (CurrentEditContext == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(DataAnnotationsValidator)} requires a cascading " +
                    $"parameter of type {nameof(EditContext)}. For example, you can use {nameof(DataAnnotationsValidator)} " +
                    $"inside an EditForm.");
            }

            _subscriptions = CurrentEditContext.EnableCustomValidation(DoEditValidation, true);
            _originalEditContext = CurrentEditContext;
        }
}
```

I have tried with Bunit:

```
public class CustomValidationTests : IDisposable
{
    private CustomValidation _customValidation;

    public CustomValidationTests()
    {
        _customValidation = new CustomValidation();
    }

    [Fact]
        public void OnInitialized_SubscribesToCustomValidation()
        {
            // Arrange
            using var ctx = new TestContext();
            var editContext = new EditContext(new object());

            // Act
            var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<CustomValidation>(
                builder => builder.Add(c => c.CurrentEditContext, editContext));

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(cut.Instance.CurrentEditContext);
        }
}
```

I have tried something like this but throws and error because of CurrentEditContext protection level because it is marked with the CascadingParameter attribute.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Whether you should test your component (that's not an extension)? Yes. Whether you should test the code inside the lifecycle methods? Yes, but it's not so easy. A better question would be *how* to test those methods?

Comment: There are two ways to test this. One is to put as much code as possible *outside* lifecycle methods, so you can test it directly. Second, you can use [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/), a Blazor unit testing framework to test the component as a whole

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can I instead use Xunit?
Because others have used this before in the project for other components. Is it possible/a good idea, to use both xunit and bunit in the same project?

Answer (score 1):

Testing lifecycle methods directly is tricky, because the way they're called is controlled by the runtime. There are two ways to test the code in them:

1. Extract the code into other methods or even classes that can be called directly and
2. Use [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/) or any other similar Blazor component testing framework that appears in the future to host and test the component.

bUnit isn't a full unit testing framework. It allows you to test components using your preferred framework eg xUnit or NUnit.

The simple test shown in [bUnit's landing page](https://bunit.dev/) would be enough to test that a simple component initializes properly, eg :

```
public class MyCounterTest:TestContext
{
  [Fact]
  public void CounterShouldIncrementWhenClicked()
  {
    // Arrange: render the Counter.razor component
    var cut = Render(@<Counter />);

    // Act: find and click the <button> element to increment
    // the counter in the <p> element
    cut.Find("button").Click();

    // Assert: first find the <p> element, then verify its content
    cut.Find("p").MarkupMatches(@<p>Current count: 1</p>);
  }    
}
```

The documentation shows how to test components with [Parameters and Cascading Values](https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/passing-parameters-to-components.html?tabs=csharp) too.

Given this component

```
public class NonBlazorTypesParams : ComponentBase
{
  [Parameter]
  public int Numbers { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public List<string> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

You can test it using the `parameters` argument of `RenderComponent`

```
public class NonBlazorTypesParamsTest : TestContext
{
  [Fact]
  public void Test()
  {
    var lines = new List<string> { "Hello", "World" };

    var cut = RenderComponent<NonBlazorTypesParams>(parameters => parameters
      .Add(p => p.Numbers, 42)
      .Add(p => p.Lines, lines)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question with what I'm trying to do with that you provided me. But CurrentEditContext is protected because it is marked with the CascadingParameter attribute. How could I proceed from this?

Comment: I haven't tried but maybe you can put a minimal EditForm in a RenderFragment and so bypass the Cascading stuff.

Comment: @HH I tried this with:
var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<CustomValidation>(
                builder => builder.AddChildContent<EditForm>(form =>
                    form.Add(c => c.EditContext, editContext)));

Still doesnt allow me to use:
// Assert
Assert.NotNull(cut.Instance.CurrentEditContext);